# how to pass raw sql query into paginator component in cakephp

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I have row sql query and i want to paginate this query with the help of cakephp paginator component.How could i ?

```
$q = "SELECT
                `UserList`.`id`,`UserList`.`user_id`,`UserList`.`list_user_id`,
                `User`.`username` ,`User`.`id` ,
                `UserDetail`.`sex`,`UserDetail`.`image`,`UserDetail`.`display_name`,`UserDetail`.`country`,`UserDetail`.`height`,`UserDetail`.`weight`,`UserDetail`.`hair_color`,`UserDetail`.`eye_color`
                from `user_lists` as `UserList` 
                inner join `users` as `User` on `UserList`.`list_user_id` = `User`.`id`
                inner join `user_details` as `UserDetail` on `UserList`.`list_user_id` = `UserDetail`.`user_id`
                where ((`UserList`.`user_id`=".$user_id.") and (`UserList`.`in_list`='short')) order by `UserList`.`created` desc limit 1";
$this->paginate = array(
                'conditions' => /*Pass $q here */,
            'limit' => 15,
            )
        );
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

### You don't

That just doesn't work, from the query in the question though, all you need is to use [pagination](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html) as normal:

```
class UserListsController extends AppController {

    public $paginate = array(
        'contain' => array(
            'User',
            'UserDetail'
        )
    );

    public function index($userId = null) {
        $conditions = array(
            'user_id' => $userId,
            'in_list' => 'short'
        );

        $data = $this->paginate($conditions);
        $this->set('data', $data);
    }

}
```